# How to write to Microsoft tasks from node.js?

Tags: node.js, api, outlook, task

The problem is my application needs to be able to write to Microsoft tasks from the code editor. How do you hard-code to write to Microsoft tasks?

My application can currently read to Microsoft tasks. I haven't tried much besides research.

**TASKS.JS**

This is the section allows the read functionalities. Read to Microsoft tasks.

```js
// Copyright (c) Microsoft. All rights reserved. Licensed under the MIT license. See LICENSE.txt in the project root for license information.
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var authHelper = require("../helpers/auth");
var graph = require("@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client");

/* GET /mail */
router.get("/", async function(req, res, next) {
  let parms = { title: "Tasks", active: { tasks: true } };

  const accessToken = await authHelper.getAccessToken(req.cookies, res);
  const userName = req.cookies.graph_user_name;
});
```

Comment: Perhaps what you want is the npm library for nodejs [Windows Scheduler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-scheduler).

Comment: You could also use the child_process module to run [schtasks.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/TaskSchd/schtasks) directly.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Client } from "@microsoft/microsoft-graph-client"

router.get("/", async function(req, res, next) {
  const accessToken = req.cookies.access_token
  const client = Client.init({
    authProvider: (done) => {
      done(null, accessToken)
    }
  })

  const result = await client
    .api("/me/planner/tasks")
    .get()`enter code here`
  res.status(200).send(result.value)
}
```